# Apache prevent access to everything except a single location

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to block access to everything on a vhost *except* a single `safe-path` (and really, everything under it, so `/safe-path/item-1`, `/safe-path/item-2`, etc); from reading the docs, it seems that I should be able to do:

```
<Location />
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Location>
<Location /safe-path>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```

But this doesn't seem to work; all URLs return a 403. I've tried the other order as well, and it doesn't seem to matter. If there's a "better" solution to the problem I'm trying to solve, I'm open to that as well.

**EDIT**: After doing some more research, I found `Require all denied` and `Require all granted`, which seems to be the 2.4 syntax. However, even setting the blocks to look like this it doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
<Location "/">
    Require all denied
</Location>
<Location "/safe-path">
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

I'm getting a 403 on every URL I hit. Even changing the order doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: From a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851999/apache-deny-location-but-allow-to-sub-location), I would set `Order Deny, Allow` in main location (/) and remove that directive in second location (/safe-path). With `allow,deny` the deny rule on the main location takes precedence though /safe-path is declared after. Note this is apache 2.2 synthax, that is not the same in apache 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it does not work with `Require` directive, but you can use instead [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html) to acheive what you want.

In this example, I disable (403 Forbidden) everything except queries that start with `/projects` (tested with an existing folder that has sub directories):

```
<Directory /my/document/root/path>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/projects
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</Directory>
```

Should work the same in a `<Location>` block.